# two php Sql Statement

Tags: mysql

Tying To Select firstname, lastname, account_badge, company 
each database has the same exact table set up. Each table has different data And Different database.

Data base one has (DB NAME: retail_office) -> firstname, lastname, account_badge, company

Data base Two has (DB NAME: back_office) -> firstname, lastname, account_badge, company

is there a way to join 2 sets of data

```
SELECT `User_First_Name`, 
       `User_Last_Name`, 
       `Account_Badge_Number`, 
       `Company` 
FROM `retail_office`.`employee_information`, `retail_office`.`employee_information`"
```

Comment: Try [`JOIN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT `User_First_Name`, `User_Last_Name`, `Account_Badge_Number`, `Company` 
FROM `retail_office`.`employee_information`

UNION ALL

SELECT `User_First_Name`, `User_Last_Name`, `Account_Badge_Number`, `Company` 
FROM `back_office`.`employee_information`
```

Comment: Thanks you very Much

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Union:

```
(SELECT `User_First_Name`, 
       `User_Last_Name`, 
       `Account_Badge_Number`, 
       `Company` 
FROM `retail_office`.`employee_information`)
UNION ALL
(SELECT `User_First_Name`, 
       `User_Last_Name`, 
       `Account_Badge_Number`, 
       `Company` 
FROM `retail_office`.`employee_information`)
```